# How to calculate fold change in gene expression from RSEM (RNAseq)

Tags: rna-seq, gene-expression, rsem, fold-change

I have gene expression data from RNAseq, specifically: log2(x+1) transformed RSEM normalized counts.

How can I convert these data from multiple samples to determine fold change in gene expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a proper statistical framework for RNA-seq dfferential analysis (which includes FC calculation). Standard tools for this are (among others) `edgeR` or `DESeq2`. You could use [tximport](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/tximport/inst/doc/tximport.html#rsem) to import RSEM outputs into R and then use its output for e.g. `DESeq2`. The linked manual provides example code for this. Please read the manuals of `edgeR` or `DESeq2` towards the respective downstream analysis. Both are extensive and compreshensive.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this information! So, just to confirm, that means that there is no 'simple formula' that can convert RSEM to fold change? Thanks again.

Comment: No. By the way, fold changes without statistics are basically meaningless. Just run it through DESeq2 and then take the results for your analysis.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will give this a try.